# Expressing a function in terms of compositions of three functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Express the function F in the form $f \circ g \circ h$.

$$F(x)=\frac  {9}{( x^2 + 7)}$$

I'm not sure how to get $x^2+7$ in the denominator. Here is what I tried:

$$h(x) = (x+7)$$

$$g(x) = x$$

$$f(x) = \frac {9}{x^2}$$

But obviously that gives me $F(x) = \dfrac {9}{(x+7)^2}$ which isn't right... any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the form of $f,g,h$? Otherwise the task does not make much sense, as one can take $h = F$, $g(x) = f(x) = x$ for example ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $\displaystyle h(x) = x^2, g(x) = x+7$ and $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{9}{x}$. So that we have $$g\circ h = x^2 +7$$ and hence $f \circ g \circ h = f\circ(g\circ h)$ which is just $$f \circ (g \circ h) = \frac{9}{x^2 + 7}$$

Comment: Lol that works! Thank you. Is there a different way to do this besides trying to solve it like a puzzle?

Comment: The easiest way here is to solve it by inspection, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s what you do in general: suppose you want to compute a value of your function. What do you do, in order? Clearly you first square your value of $x$; then you add $7$; then you divide the result into $9$. Now traanslate each of these steps into functional notation, and you have it.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot!